# Voltage rating on panel jack

Tags: voltage, maximum-ratings

I'm building a power converter that will take 20 VDC input. I have a cable with a 1.7 x 4.0 mm plug, so I'm trying to find a suitable panel mount jack.

Online, I've found [this](https://vetco.net/products/1-7mm-dc-power-panel-mount-jack) model. 
On the Philmore Web site, the specs say this jack is rated at 6.3 VDC.

How much of a chance would I be taking by using this underspec'ed jack? I haven't found another suitable model.

Answer (score 2):

6.3V isn't the *physical* rating of the plug, but the *regulatory* rating. 4mm OD × 1.7mm ID is [type EIAJ-02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIAJ_connector), part of a series of sizes of barrel connector intended to provide some correlation between plug dimensions and voltage. Type 02 is for voltages between 3.15V and 6.3V, but likely would work with higher voltages.

Given that the connector itself is intended not to be used with anything above 6.3V in order to prevent damaging devices (from plugging in the wrong voltage connector), I wouldn't recommend using this connector for this purpose.

Comment: @PaulSteckler And let me reiterate that I think going against this standard is a bad idea. It's the same reason you don't get low-voltage things with NEMA 5 connectors on them: you don't want it to be possible to plug the wrong thing into the wrong place and blow stuff up. Unfortunately, because of the ubiquity of 2.1mm×5.5mm barrel jacks and similar, this is clearly rarely followed advice, especially when the only risk presented is that of breaking things, not actually harming people.

Comment: Thanks. The cable I have is a USB C "trigger" cable that outputs 20 volts only, so it's not adhering to the standard. Presumably, the cable was manufactured because there are devices that use this connector and require 20 volts. There are other similar trigger cables with different connectors. Maybe it would be a good idea to use one that has a jack meant for higher voltages.